# aerocool v3x no front fan case screw holes

Tags: fan, cooling, computer-building, desktop-computer, case

Hey guys I have an Aerocool V3X case with preinstalled rear fan and I can install 2 side fans and one front fan. I went to install the front fan but there are no screw holes! There is a "mesh" but no screwholes to mount the fan! From other videos I can see that the preinstalled front fan (Mine is the same case, but it doesn't have a front fan and USB 3) isn't even screwed! How is it installed then?
Here is a video showing the front fan (My camera sucks sorry for not providing pics).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ulvWUCqip4
(somewhere on 8:50, how is the fan installed? Maybe it touches the hard disk's box?)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no need to screw the fan! I could not install the fan because it was not SQUARE, it needed a square fan, mine was oval. Got an Arctic F12 PWM, and I installed it in seconds, you just push the fan and it installs without screwing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the mesh? From the question I cannot tell if you have or not, but the mesh is often in front of the fans to prevent dust getting into the system at all, and for easier access. If you are absolutely certain there are no holes you can always drill them yourself, they may have been a manufacturing error.